# 20kHz PWM on Arduino

Tags: pwm

The datasheet of the [ST VNH5050A-E H-bridge motor driver](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/6b/3d/8c/73/0c/a2/44/5e/CD00241540.pdf/files/CD00241540.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00241540.pdf) says it can take PWM up to 20kHz. Then, on page 10 of the datasheet, it says PWM = 20 kHz in the supply current parameter. Does this mean that the PWM frequency has to **be** 20kHz or, as it says in the description, it can be **up to** 20kHz?

Arduino Mega runs default PWM at 490Hz if I am not mistaken.  I am trying to find a driver chip that can handle at least 30 amps with a load voltage of up to 12-18V for a motor.

I'm trying to figure out if this chip will work with the PWM on the Arduino Mega.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification of 8mA supply current (maximum) is guaranteed at 20kHz and under the other conditions stated.

The PWM can be any frequency from 0 to 20kHz.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you!